# Swift Looping Over a List

Tags: swift

I'm trying to find if a string is in a word list read from a file.  This is what I have so far.  The content?[index] does seem to work.  But the loop/optional stuff is causing things to not work.

Also, there is an efficiency question.  Is it maybe better to put a list into a dictionary and have keys as say the first letter or something?  Then try to see if that object exists with the same key instead of looping through the whole list each time.

```
      let testString = "Hello"    

      let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wordlist", ofType: "txt")
        var content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)?.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

      let count = content?.count

      for word in 0..<count
      {
        if testString == content?[word]{
        // fount word}
      }
```

It complains about count being an int? instead of an int.  Thanks for suggestions on how to work this best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
let count = content?.count
```

which is an optional (`Int?`). The solution would be to unwrap it with a conditional:

```
if let count = content?.count {
    for word in 0..<count
        {
            if testString == content?[word] {
                // fount word}
        }
    }
}
```

As for the algorithm, it depends from the usage. If you do one search only, then the current implementation is good, which is an O(n).

In case of multiple searches, I would use this algorithm:

- sort all keys
- sort all words
- then loop through both
- compare key with word:

  - if equal, 1 word is found, advance key and continue the loop
  - if less, advance word and continue
  - if greater, advance key and continue
- loop ends when either no other key or no other word is available.

Not sure, but complexity should be O(N), plus the cost of sorting the 2 lists.

**Addendum** A better way to implement that loop is:

```
if let content = content {
    for word in 0 ..< content.count
    {
        if testString == content[word] {
            // fount word}
        }
    }
}
```

Unwrap once and use anywhere (but within the block).

**Addendum 2** A better algorithm is the following:

Store all keys in a hashset. Loop through all words, check if the word is in the set, and if yes add to the list of the found words. Much simpler.

If the number of words is less than the number of keys, I would invert that, by populating the hashset from the list of words and looping through the keys.

The complexity of this algorithm should be at most O(2n), where n is the max between the number of keys and the number of words.

Comment: That fixes my looping problem, but it seems like there is an issue with the equality test.  It doesn't find words that are in the list.

var testString = "HELLO"


        if let count = content?.count {
            for word in 0..<count
            {
                
                if testString == content?[word].uppercaseString || testString == content?[word].lowercaseString {
                    println("Word Found:\(testString)")
                }
            }
        }
       println("Strings to test \(testString)  and \(content?[3].uppercaseString) ")

Comment: If I assign testString directly say content[3] it finds the match, but not if I just manually input the string.

Comment: Are you using non ascii characters? Have you tried trimming before comparing? Try reading this blog post and see if it applies in your case: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/

Comment: Have you read the article I mentioned in the prev comment? Have you tried checking their length? Are you sure there's no extra character (such as a \n or \r)?